# cannot see tabs for manage fields etc with administrative toolbars add content bar

Tags: toolbar

This must be something new because never seen it before now. There is a grey bar with the add content find content and edit shortcuts links on it which completely obscure the tabs for manage field etc in content types.

How can I keep the administration toolbar but remove that grey bar? AND WHY would anyone want it placed in such a way as to block out important regularly used tabs?

Answer (score 1):

It's an incompatibility between administration toolbar and your theme, and maybe overlay if you are using it. No one placed it like that on purpose, it's just a clash between 3 sets of CSS each written without knowing how other will look.

You can try one or many of the following:

- Use [Administration menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) instead of toolbar.
- Use [Shiny](https://drupal.org/project/shiny) as admin theme
- Toggle overlay - if it's on, maybe without it it'll be OK? If it's off, maybe it'll help?
- Create a subtheme and deliver CSS that will position stuff the way it should be for your particular case. Firebug or Chrome are good for fast prototyping your fix.